# Running Code When a Module is Loaded and Exposing It as Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am still trying to fully understand how exporting and importing modules works in Nodejs.

I am using the following file to seed a mongodb database. This file runs exactly as it should and returns exactly the result I am expecting, when I execute it as a standalone file. My issue is I want to use this file in two different places in my app. So I am trying to make it an exportable/importable module. Here is what I have tried:

seed.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

//  library modules

const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');

const seeder     = require('mongoose-seed');

const jwt        = require('jsonwebtoken');

const util       = require('util');

//  local modules

const {Course}   = require('./../models/course');

const {Review}   = require('./../models/review');

const {User}     = require('./../models/user');

const {data}     = require('./../data/data.js');

const config     = require('./../config/config.js');

/*==================================================

    build seeding Courses, Reviews, Users
==================================================*/

// Connect to MongoDB via Mongoose

let seed = seeder.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, (e) => {
    console.log(`Connected to: ${process.env.MONGODB_URI} and seeding files`);

    // Load Mongoose models
    seeder.loadModels([
        'src/models/user.js',
        'src/models/review.js',
        'src/models/course.js'
    ]);

    // Clear specified collections
    seeder.clearModels(['User', 'Review', 'Course'], function() {

        // Callback to populate DB once collections have been cleared
            seeder.populateModels(data, function() {
            seeder.disconnect();
        });

    });
});

module.exports = seed;
```

Within app.js I have these two lines

```
const seed         = require('./middleware/seed');
```

and

```
app.use(seed);
```

I have also tried, to no avail

```
app.use(seed());
```

What is missing? I don't want to use the code in-line in two different places (DRY you know).

It is failing with this error:

```
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
```

I am sorry about the formatting I thought I was using markdown, but I am clearly not.

Comment: Marcos Casagrande: Thank you for the editing. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing your seeder  function in that module and not returning any middleware function at all. Middleware is always a function and it has the form of:

```
const seed = function (req, res, next) {
  ...
  next()
}
```

With what you have now, the best you can do is the following which will certainly seed your models when the module is loaded.

```
const seed  = require('./middleware/seed');
```

Are you trying to run those two functions as middleware, on every request?  In that case you'd do something like this:

```
const seed = function (req, res, next) {
    seeder.connect(..., (e) => {
       ...
       seeder.clearModels(..., ()=>{
          ...
          next()
       })
    })
})
```

If you want to run that seeder code at the module level AND to expose it as middleware then wrap the current module level code in function and execute it when the module loads. Notice that the new function optionally handles the next callback if it receives it.

```
function doSeed(next){
   //your code currently running at module level
   if(next)
       return next()
}
 doSeed();  //run the code at the module level
 const seed =  (req, res, next) => doSeed(next))
 module.exports = seed;
```

Comment: Robert Moskal: You da man! Thank you so much. sometimes a rookie just needs a bit of help. I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I allow myself to have access to a variable in different instances is adding it to the process variable. In node.js no matter where in the project it is, it will always be the same. In some cases, I would do `process.DB = seed();` which would allow process.DB to always be the result of that. So inside your main class you can do `process.DB = seed();` and all of your other classes running off of that one main class would have access to process.DB keeping your database readily available.